# launch error: using eclipse cdt with visual c compiler error(cl.exe)

Tags: c++, eclipse, visual-c++, eclipse-cdt

I try to using eclipse 3.7 cdt with visual c++ compiler to compile my cpp code appling default setting. 
the compile and link process are ok. But the program still could not launch with an error.
"A program file was not specified in the launch configuration."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See [this IBM article](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/os-eclipse-cdt-debug1/index.html) (about the debug configuration, but also useful for a "run" configuration):

[image]

You need to specify the Project and executable to run.